# How to send extra data with addTrack in webRTC peer connection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simple-peer

I am adding multiple `tracks` from different clients to the `peer` and I was wondering if it is possible to send extra data with `addTrack` to identify which track belongs to which user? Without a nominator it is impossible for me to tell which `track` is sent by who.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaStream id (but not the track ids) to create such a mapping and send it as additional metadata along with your offer or answer.

https://webrtccourse.com/course/webrtc-codelab/module/fiddle-of-the-month/lesson/multiple-video-tracks-on-a-single-peer-connection/ has a lengthy discussion of the topic,